# Kafka Consumer partition assignment delayed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

When using the Kafka consumer `subscribe(Collection<String> topics, ConsumerRebalanceListener listener)` API, I'm using the `onPartitionsAssigned` callback in `ConsumerRebalanceListener` to seek newly subscribed partitions to certain offsets, and print them in log. However sometimes I see a significant delay of the consumer partition assignment on a subset of partitions.

For example, assuming I have a topic `topicA` which has **two** partitions, I initialize and run my consumer this way:

```
Collection<String> topic = Arrays.asList("topicA");
consumer.subscribe(topic, new MyLoggingListener);
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<K, V>  records = consumer.poll(1000L);
    System.out.println("receiving records from " + records.partitions());
    //...process the results and print records
}

static class MyLoggingListener<K, V> implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // no-op
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        partitions.forEach(topicPartition -> System.out.println("now subscribing to " + topicPartition));
    }
}
```

Ideally and usually I see logs like this:

```
now subscribing to topicA-0
now subscribing to topicA-1
receiving records from [topicA-0, topicA-1]
receiving records from [topicA-0, topicA-1]
...
...
```

but sometimes I see

```
now subscribing to topicA-0
receiving records from [topicA-0]
receiving records from [topicA-0]
...
... //for a very long time like an hour
...
now subscribing to topicA-1
receiving records from [topicA-0, topicA-1]
receiving records from [topicA-0, topicA-1]
```

Does anyone have any insight on the root cause of this strange behavior? Is Kafka broker under high pressure and too busy to assign partitions to a new consumer?